# Typescript + Angular2: Subscribing to Observable causes "Unrecognized teardown 1" error

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I have an issue with using an Observable in an Angular2.rc.4 Typescript app.  I have a plunker for it here:
https://embed.plnkr.co/UjcdCmN6hSkdKt27ezyI/

Essentially the app has a service which has this code:

```
private messageSender : Observable<string>;

constructor() {
    this.messageSender = Observable.create(observer => this.clients.push(observer));
 }

public listenForMessages() : any {
    console.log("Listen Requested...")
    return this.messageSender;
}
```

And I want to listen to it from a component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.chatter.listenForMessages().subscribe(msg => console.log(msg));
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Unrecognized teardown 1 added to Subscription.
Error: Unrecognized teardown 1 added to Subscription.
    at Subscriber.Subscription.add (Subscription.ts:151)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.ts:93)
    at LoginPage.ngOnInit (login.ts:15)
    at DebugAppView._View_LoginPage_Host0.detectChangesInternal (LoginPage.template.js:29)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:261)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:377)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.ts:280)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChangesInternal (view.ts:272)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:261)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:377)
BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:82
```

The same error occurs if a transpile tsc or allow that to happen in the browser, and if I target either ES6 or ES5.

I have been looking at it for hours, I have found no references to it on any other site.  That error message comes from RxJS, it examines the thing passed into the .subscribe() method, checks if its type is 'object' or 'function' and will emit this error if it is neither.  I have passed lambdas as in the plunker, or pre-defined functions and they result in the same problem.

Any ideas?  If I create the Observable in the component, then there is no problem.  If I subscribe in the service then I get the same error...  So confused.

Comment: maybe do: private messageSender : Observable<any>; or private messageSender : Observable<any[]>;

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  Also, perhaps weirdly, if you start feeding values through the Observable they do get received despite the error, but other functions (most notably Angular2 lifecycle methods) don't get executed.  So the subscribe works but the app is in a bad state after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `Array#push` returns a number (which is the new length of the `Array`) and it is trying to use that as the new `TeardownLogic` when you do `Observable.create(observer => this.clients.push(observer))`.

I suggest that you **do not** use the *observer-array* pattern, you are just reinventing the wheel honestly and it is unlikely that you will do it properly (*note: it isn't just you, I've seen it popping up in ng2 tutorials and it is just a awful, awful pattern).

If you need multi-cast behavior you should be using a `Subject` instead:

```
private messageSender : Subject<string>;

constructor() {
    this.messageSender = new Subject<string>();
 }

public listenForMessages() : any {
    console.log("Listen Requested...")
    return this.messageSender.asObservable();
}
```

An even better solution would be to do away with the intermediate `Subject` altogether and subscribe directly to the message source, but without knowing more about your application I can't actually say how you might hook that up.

Comment: Uhhhg!  Thanks so much for seeing that, I was lost where the 1 was coming from even after stepping through the code.   The Subject will work for me.  The original source will be a single we socket that feeds different content as JSON. Clients of the observable will care about a subset of the content and I want to hide both the source and the need to filter out content from the client.  The Subject looks correct both functionally but also semantically.  Thanks again.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Hi paul - i just came across your answer after encountering the same error - do you have any resources that you can supply so that I can read up on when to/when not to use Subject via Observable<Array<?>> It seems that if you return a Subject instead of an Observable then it's basically like returning a deferred instead of a promise in Angular 1. Thoughts?

Comment: @Katana24 The Subject API is here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md.  Subject is a one to many mapping between Observable to Observers (allows one Observable to trigger actions on multiple Observers), which I don't think deferred does with Promise (but I could be wrong).  But similar to what deferred does to Promise, Subject also provides an interface to trigger those actions on the multiple Observers yourself (i.e. your code acts as the Observable input to Subject).

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who has a similar error message. You are probably not passing `Object.create` a callback function the returns `TeardownLogic`. Where:

```
export type TeardownLogic = AnonymousSubscription | Function | void;
```

and where

```
export interface AnonymousSubscription {
  unsubscribe(): void;
}
```

For example, I was returning a `boolean`:

```
this.showSomething = Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => this.code === "00108");
```

when I should have been returning an `AnonymousSubscription`:

```
this.showSomething = Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
    observer.next(this.code === "00108");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just completing @Tom answer, I was facing the same problem because I was not handling the Observer.

**Wrong implementation:**

```
@Injectable()
export class QuizEditorGuard implements CanDeactivate<QuizEditorPage> {

  constructor(private app: ApplicationService) { }

  canDeactivate(
    quizEditor: QuizEditorPage,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
      if (quizEditor && quizEditor.hasUnsavedChanges) {
        observer.next(true);
        observer.complete();
      }
      else
        return false; //here is the problem
    });
  }
}
```

**Correct Implementation:**

```
@Injectable()
export class QuizEditorGuard implements CanDeactivate<QuizEditorPage> {

  constructor(private app: ApplicationService) { }

  canDeactivate(
    quizEditor: QuizEditorPage,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
      if (quizEditor && quizEditor.hasUnsavedChanges) {
        observer.next(true);
        observer.complete();
      }
      else {
        observer.next(false); //always implement next to warn observer
        observer.complete();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Heading back to @Steven question, his error happened for the same reason: He was creating an observer without telling his object what to do after client insertion.

```
Observable.create(observer => 
    this.clients.push(observer));
    observer.next("some string");
    observer.complete();
 }
```